# Как сделать outline для ссылок 'a' вокруг текста разной длины

Tags: html, css, width, focus, outline

Хочу задать ссылкам `a` `:focus` с `outline` вокруг текста, но `outline` выходит длиннее, чем текст с правой стороны. Я пытался исправить это путем добавления определенной ширины `width`, но у каждой ссылки текст совсем разной длины и поэтому это не помогает. Как можно это исправить?
Код приведен ниже

```css
.contacts-item-link {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 180%;
  color: #000;
}

.contacts-item-link:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #71A7E2;
}

.contacts-item-link:hover {
  color: #71A7E2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="main">
              <a href="tel:79876543210" class="contacts-item-link">
                +7 (987) 654-32-10
              </a>
              <a href="tel:71234567890" class="contacts-item-link">
                +7 (123) 456-78-90
              </a>
              <a href="mailto:example@example.com" class="contacts-item-link">
                example@example.com
              </a>
              <a href="mailto:support@example.com" class="contacts-item-link">
                support@example.com
              </a>
</main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию ссылки имеют обводку по ширине текста, так как у них свойство *display* установлено в *inline*. Но, Вы задали этому свойству значение *block* (предполагаю, чтобы ссылки были каждая с новой строки), разрешая растягиваться на всю доступную ширину.

Ссылки или не трогаем или задаём значение *inline-block*, а выравниваем в колонку через `display: flex` у родителя :

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.contacts-item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 180%;
  color: #000;
}

.contacts-item-link:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #71A7E2;
}

.contacts-item-link:hover {
  color: #71A7E2;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <a href="tel:79876543210" class="contacts-item-link">+7 (987) 654-32-10</a>
  <a href="tel:71234567890" class="contacts-item-link">+7 (123) 456-78-90</a>
  <a href="mailto:example@example.com" class="contacts-item-link">example@example.com</a>
  <a href="mailto:support@example.com" class="contacts-item-link">support@example.com</a>
</main>
```